# Laravel blade @section does not work

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade, vuetify.js

I built a Basic blade template inside

> resources/views
>   ,

Further I am using Vuetify.

it look like this:

```
//app.blade.php:

<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

        <title>{{ config('app.name', env('APP_NAME')) }}</title>

        <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="app" dark>
            <v-app dark v-if="loading">
                <v-layout row wrap align-center>
                    <v-flex class="text-xs-center">
                        <v-progress-circular :indeterminate="true" :size="80" color="primary"></v-progress-circular>
                    </v-flex>
                </v-layout>
            </v-app>
            <v-app v-else v-cloak dark>
                <v-navigation-drawer app right></v-navigation-drawer>
                <v-toolbar app></v-toolbar>
                <v-content>
                    <v-container grid-list-xl>
                        <v-layout>
                            @section('content')
                        </v-layout>
                    </v-container>
                </v-content>
                <v-footer app></v-footer>
            </v-app>
        </div>

        <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
        @yield('javascript')
    </body>
</html>
```

I create a section 
`@section('content')` so that I can extend the layout and put Content to that area. Inside

> resources/views/Event

i have a blade file which extends this and shall add data to the Content

```
    // create.blade.php

@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    testests    
@endsection
```

But Nothing gets shown, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

In you Blade template, you want to use

```
@yield('content')
```

not:

```
@section('content')
```